# The table does not exist: {{%active_record}}

Tags: yii2, gii

I am new to yii and learing generating the CRUD operation through gii first i create a country table and generate the model and controller and views using gii i am get following error
Invalid Configuration – yii\base\InvalidConfigException The table does not exist: {{%country_search}}

Comment: Are you properly connected to your database and is there this table `country_search`?

Comment: yes i am sure that connected to database but i have only country table but no country_search table actually i simply follow the rules of http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-start-gii.html docs kindly suggest

Comment: You need first to create this table in your database and then you can use Gii to generate code for it in Yii.

Comment: ok sir solved it thank you

Answer (score 3):

Add this to CountrySearch class:

```
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
     public static function tableName()
     {
         return 'country';
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just adding to temirbek answer:

file models/Country.php

```
<?php

namespace app\models;

use yii\db\ActiveRecord;

class Country extends ActiveRecord
{
     public static function tableName()
     {
         return 'country';
     }

}
```